# Convergence of iterated integrals in rough-path integration

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, rough-path-theory

I'm trying to understand the proof of Lemma 6 (p. 27) in "An Introduction to Rough Paths" - A. Lejay.

He first defines the $\mathbf{y}_{s, t}^1$ to be
$$\mathbf{y}_{s, t}^1 = f(x_s) \mathbf x_{s, t}^1 + \nabla f(x_s) \mathbf x_{s, t}^2,$$
where $\mathbf x_{s, t}^1$ are the path increments and $\mathbf x_{s, t}^2$ are the (postulated) first iterated integrals. In the beginning of the proof of Lemma 6, he then says
$$\mathbf{y}_{s, u}^1 \otimes \mathbf{y}_{u, t}^1 = f(x_s) \mathbf x_{s, u}^1 \otimes f(x_u) \mathbf x_{u, t}^1.$$

Now, my question is what happens to the other terms? I understand, that in the truncated tensor algebra $T_2(\mathbb R^n)$, all terms of tensor level $\geq 3$ are ignored, but for that to be used, one would have to pull the $\nabla f(x_s)$ out of the tensor product and I don't see why this should be allowed.